# Duda sobre el pasaje de datos de una lista a una variable entera

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas a todos les comento la idea aqui es que a un Id de un Expediente se le puede asignar a varios usuarios

ej `IdExpediente: 51` se le puede asignar a los `IdMail: 17 y 58` y eso se guarda en la tabla `T_MAIL_EXP` como puedo hacer para que se cargue en la tabla de la manera en que muestre

```
Id Expediente   Id_Mail
51              17
51              58
```

Este sería el codigo:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Asignar(FormCollection coleccion)
    {
        string _exp_id = Request["exp"];
        string _username = "";
        //int _id_Expediente;
        if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        _username = this.User.Identity.Name;
        try
        {
            T_EXP_ENVIO dbExpEnvio = new T_EXP_ENVIO()
            {
                N__Expediente = _exp_id
            };
            _seguimientoExpServicio.AgregarExpediente(dbExpEnvio);
            var IdExpEnvio = _seguimientoExpServicio.ObtenerIdExpEnvio(_exp_id);
            var lista = _seguimientoExpServicio.ObtenerIdMailPorUsuario(_username);
            T_MAIL_EXP dbMailExp = new T_MAIL_EXP()
            {
                 id_Expediente = IdExpEnvio,
                // id_Mails = lista.Sele
            };
```

Comment: Hola PJ, bienvenido. Puedes poner el codigo en formato de texto? con la imagen es dificil de leer y no se puede copiar y pegar

Comment: Ahi esta es el del HttpPost

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Tu problema es al añadir la lista de mails a `dbMailExp`? O como mostrar en el UI los datos? Necesitariamos probablemente tambien ver la definición de `T_MAIL_EXP`

Comment: Hola mira es bastante larga la cuestion es un proyecto que trabaja con un modelo vista controlador y mira la idea es que a la tabla T_MAIL_EXP se le asigne un Id del Expediente con un Id del Mail osea ej el id_Expediente : 20 que se le asigne al Id_Mail: 17 y 58
La T_MAIL_EXP es una tabla en sql server no es un UI que haya que mostrar

Comment: Id_Mails de que tipo es? De todas maneras, si T_MAIL_EXP es una tabla del SQL, solo veo dos opciones: o metes los id's de mail en un campo separados por algun caracter, o tendrás que crear dos filas. Pero todavia no termino de entender exactamente lo que quieres

Comment: @pj2016 de tu pregunta entiendo que no sabes como tomar los valores de una lista que están en el `FormCollection`. Si esto es correcto, seria bueno que editaras la pregunta y pusieras el código HTML que tengas en la vista, para poder ver que tipo de control estas usando o como estas nombrando los controles para lo que llamas `lista`.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente deberias crear varios objetos `T_MAIL_EXP` uno por cada `Id_Mail` distinto y manteniendo el `id_Expediente`, luego persistís de la forma que venís persistiendo hasta ahora.
Entonces en BD te va a quedar tal cual como queres:

```
Id Expediente   Id_Mail
51              17
51              58
```